# Iterator printing from vector unneeded values

Tags: c++, vector

The intended nature of the program is to randomly generate numbers into a vector container, then sort them in ascending order and print the numbers out. The program compiles correctly but also sorts and prints the value `0` for each number that is generated.

```
#include "stdafx.h"  
//contains all header files (ctime, algorithm, iostream, vector), also 
defines const vector size as 250

using namespace std;

void genRndNums(vector <int> &v);
void printVec(vector <int> &v);

int main()
{
    vector <int> myVector(VEC_SIZE);
    genRndNums(myVector);
    printVec(myVector);
    return 0;
}

void genRndNums(vector <int> &v)
{
    int v1;
    srand(time(nullptr));

    for (int i = 0; i < VEC_SIZE; i++)
    {
        v1 = rand() % 1000 + 1;
        v.push_back(v1);

        //v.push_back(rand() % 1000 + 1);
    }
}

void printVec(vector <int> &v)
{
    vector<int>::iterator it;
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << "     ";
    }
}
```

In the case that `250` numbers were printed out, it would display the integer `0` **250 times** and then display the rest of the numbers in ascending sequence.

This is due to the for-loop in the print function having something misplaced, but I am not sure how to get the vector to display only the randomized integers.

Comment: It is the vector <int> myVector(VEC_SIZE). This declares a vector with VEC_SIZE entries initialized to 0

Comment: May want to investigate the reserve method on std::vector.  I suspect this is what you were trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `push_back` to add elements to the vector, you need to start with an empty vector. I.e. you need to replace `vector <int> myVector(VEC_SIZE);` with `vector <int> myVector;`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake. `push_back` adds to the end of the vector whose size is already `VEC_SIZE`. You can start with an empty vector like this:

```
vector <int> myVector;
```

or you can assign values to existing vector (whose size is `VEC_SIZE`) elements like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < VEC_SIZE; i++)
{
    v1 = rand() % 1000 + 1;
    v[i] = v1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vector constructor creates vector with 250 numbers (each with 0 value). To that numbers you appends another 250 generated numbers.

You shall not create that 250 numbers at the beginning

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    {
        std::random_device r;
        std::default_random_engine e(r());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(1, 6);
        std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(v), 250, [&](){ return d(r); });
    }

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or override them

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(250);
    {
        std::random_device r;
        std::default_random_engine e(r());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(1, 6);
        std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](){ return d(r); });
    }

    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    for (auto x : v) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```